# Advice for Removing Raceway Wiremolds

Tags: drywall, paint, removal, adhesive

I'm trying to remove several [Raceway Wiremolds](http://www.legrand.us/wiremold/raceway/nonmetallic-raceway/single-channel-raceway/400-800-2300-powerrated-raceway/400-800-2300-powerrated-raceway.aspx#.VUU9NM543dk).

A few of the Wiremolds seems to be firmly stuck to the drywall. I'm worried if I pull too hard it will rip out chunks of paint/drywall. Any advice on removing them?

[image]

I was able to remove some of the Wiremolds - but they left a sticky residue behind. Any recommendations on how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try running a putty knife or something behind them, but my actual advice for removing them is to have the spackle or drywall compound and paint handy, as scars are to be expected.

Hmm - heat  (as from a hair dryer - not so much as to scorch paint) might also help loosen the adhesive a bit.

As for the left-behind adhesive the usual suspects - goof-off, paint thinner, cleaning sprays, try various things looking for one that gets the adhesive but not the paint, or wait for a more specific suggestion here from someone who's done it recently.

Comment: +1 It's what I would have said - putty knife, heat, expect scars, goo-gone...